# Read cell style using fastexcel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, fast-excel

Is it possible to read or discover styles applied to cells in excel sheet using fastexcel library in Java?

I'd like to find out what color is applied to cell background or what color is applied to a font but not sure if this is possible with this library. Am I limited to Apache poi in this case?

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader supports streaming reads and you can enable style support - see the README and its reference to the Builder class (the `readStyles()` method)